# Cannot synchronize project to QFieldCloud from QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfield-cloud

I'm new to QGIS and QField. I try to synchronize data to QFieldCloud, but I get the following error:

> Missing primary key. QFieldCloud supports only layers with a defined
> single-column primary key. Please change the layer action to 'Remove'
> in 'Layer Properties -> QField'.

I don't want to remove the layer. What should I do?

Comment: You need to create a primary key - a unique ID field. What source is your layer?